# Website requiring Adobe Flash will not load

Tags: flash

I recently purchased a new Windows 10 laptop. I want to run a Spectrum Live TV website to view TV in an Always On Top session. This website requires Adobe Flash (version 32.0.0.255 is loaded on the PC), and when the website is opened it displays a message saying Adobe must be downloaded and I cannot get past it. When I run either Chrome or Edge the website works fine, but I get a popup box asking if Flash is allowed to run. I do not get this popup box when running Always On Top.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Flash.

Each works on a different protocol, either NPAPI or PPAPI.
Different browsers/apps require different protocols.

Check which one you have & try the other one - you can have both on the same machine without issue.

See [Adobe's Flash download site](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) where you can choose either type for any OS.